# asynchronous programming using tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Alright, I want to keep this short and precise, I'm trying to find the most efficient way to get a large amount of HttpWebRequests completed but I'm slightly confused, if I have a List of tasks and I use the Task.WaitAll function to await until all tasks have completed, is it overkill to make the Task (Action) in the list also an async task? Maybe I can explain myself better in code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => DoSomething()));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

Ok so pretty simple, I have a for loop that'll run the DoSomething method on available threads within the ThreadPool, now let's take two different looks at how I can implement this DoSomething() function

```
public void DoSomething()
{
Send off the HttpWebRequest here, with no awaits or any async programming
}
```

OR

```
public Task<ResponseData> DoSomething()
{
Write the request here that awaits for responses, streams etc
}
```

If I am already sending the DoSomething function off to the Task.Run function doesnt that already mean it's running on it's own Thread in the ThreadPool ? meaning making the DoSomething function an actual task and implementing awaits/async functionality within that scope becomes redundant? wouldnt that just waste more resources?

Comment: Impossible to answer without more context. Does `DoSomething()` do anything _other_ than make your HTTP request? Do you need for it to do something _after_ the request is done? If all you're doing is the request, then you should use the async request API, return from `DoSomething()` the `Task` representing the request, and just add _that_ to your list instead of using `Task.Run()`. If `DoSomething()` has more processing to do after the request, you should do the same, but you can `await` in it. Either way, it's unlikely you need `Task.Run()`. But who can tell, since you didn't share code.

Comment: So a function that returns a task is already accessing a thread on the threadpool as if I was passing a non-task returning function into Task.Run?

So Task.Run(() => DoSomething()); would be the same as creating a function that returns a task?

Comment: _"a function that returns a task is already accessing a thread on the threadpool?"_ -- not necessarily, no. But it _is_ operating asynchronously, and that's what you care about in the code above. Don't confuse "asynchronous" with "concurrent" or "threaded". The two are closely related, but are not the same. There are asynchronous mechanisms that don't rely on an active thread.

Comment: So one last thing, iterating over a collection of objects and calling a function which returns a task in each iteration with awaits in that scope would give the same affect as adding Task.Run(() => NonTaskFunction) to a list of tasks and then awaiting it? But the more optimal, and 'proper' way of doing this would be to actually use the task api and implement the appropriate function yes? Iterating over a collection of objects in which the only thing I do is call the async task would give me the parralel/multithreaded aspect im looking for

Comment: So to conclude, having an async Task DoSomething() containing awaits and calling Task.Run(() => DoSomething is completely useless and unnecessary as a Task is already 'running' anyway as the function signature implies. I should only use Task.Run if I have a function or functions that need to be completed on a separate thread and said function isn't already a Task itself I guess

Comment: _"I should only use Task.Run if I have a function or functions that need to be completed on a separate thread and said function isn't already a Task"_ -- yes, while necessarily over-simplistic because of the brevity required in comments, I'd say that's a reasonable summary.

Comment: If you want to wait in `async` fashion, use `await Task.WhenAll();`

Answer (score 2):

> If I am already sending the DoSomething function off to the Task.Run
>   function doesnt that already mean it's running on it's own Thread in
>   the ThreadPool ? **meaning making the DoSomething function an actual
>   task and implementing awaits/async functionality within that scope
>   becomes redundant**?

Opposite - you are wasting resources when you using another thread (`Task.Run`) for the method which "do nothing" - waiting for the response.

`await Task.Run(() => DoSomethingSynchronously)` and `await DoSomethingAsynchronously()` are different things, because properly created `async-await` method will executes on the one thread.
In your case it will send request and return execution back to the caller. After response arrived it will continue execution after await.

So using `Task.Run` with methods which do nothing - only waiting for response become wasting of resources(threads).

Because your `DoSomething` method works with external resource (webervices), you don't need to worry about ThreadPool and threads at all. All tasks can be done asynchronously in one thread with `async-await` approach.

Comment: I didnt understand fully what youre trying to say on the 3rd parahraph, but ill try to clarify. 
The are 2 options, either waiting for tasks 1-by-1 or just to wait everyone.
waiting 1-by-1 is just if you really want to reduce resource useage or have something to do with the previous result of a task.
Awaiting all means, "just finish everything until this point before moving on". Regardless to what you use, you MUST ALWAYS await an async task/s in the end of a method (unless moving it forward for another method) or else, youll have a racing condition which is bad.

Comment: @OriRefael, I wasn't talking about multiple tasks, In third paragraph I tried "rawly" explain that asynchronous method can be executed in one thread.

Comment: I wanted to clarify the approach of using async-await when one has multiple tasks.

Comment: @OriRefael - In case of two tasks, if second task not depend on result of first - then you can start both almost simultaneously and "await" when both tasks completes: `await Task.WhenAll(new[] { getOneAsync(), getAnotherAsync() })`. If second task depends on result of first then you will "await" first before starting second: `var customerId = await getCustomerIdAsync(); await getOrderByCustomerIdAsync(customerId);`

Comment: thats what I said :) Im not the OP nor someone who asked a question